# Fast dictionary population with list of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d = {} # or d = defaultdict(int)

list_of_lists = [[9, 7, 5, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7], [3, 5, 8, 1]]

for lst in list_of_lists:
    for key in lst:
        try:
            d[key] += 1
        except:
            d[key] = 1
```

Is there a way to perform this operation without the for-loops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a generator expression:

```
from collections import Counter

d = Counter(i for nested in list_of_lists for i in nested)
```

or replacing the generator expression with `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`:

```
from itertools import chain

d = Counter(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list_of_lists = [[9, 7, 5, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7], [3, 5, 8, 1]]
>>> Counter(i for nested in list_of_lists for i in nested)
Counter({3: 4, 1: 3, 5: 3, 2: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1})
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
Counter({3: 4, 1: 3, 5: 3, 2: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1})
```

Comment: If one list at time is being processed, then how would using Counter accumulate the results ie. the inner "key in lst" loop?

Comment: @HenryThornton: the generator expression embodies the same nested loops your code used; read the loops from left to right as if nested. So for each nested list in the `list_of_lists` object an inner loop `for i in nested` is executed and the `Counter()` is passed each `i` from those nested lists.

Comment: @HenryThornton: the `chain.from_iterable()` call delegates the double looping to C code; `chain.from_iterable()` takes each nested list and loops over those in order, producing a flat sequence of the contained numbers.

Comment: Got it. This requires that list_of_lists is fixed. What if list_of_lists was open-ended ie. lists are continously generated. It is slightly different from original question.

Comment: @HenryThornton: you mean it is a generator? That doesn't matter to either technique, provided the generator is not without end.

Comment: @HenryThornton: you can *add* to an existing `Counter()` object with `d.update(more_values_to_count)`, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to count the frequency of each integer in your list of lists.

You can do this with `numpy.bincount`.  The actual counting is very fast, as the core of `numpy` is C++. Some work needs to be done to get the data in the dictionary format -- you could potentially just use the `numpy.array` generated by this.  The majority of this code is just converting from different formats, which you could do away with if your application allows.

```
list_of_lists = [[9, 7, 5, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7], [3, 5, 8, 1]]

import numpy as np
x = sum(list_of_lists, []) #convert your list of lists to a flat list
y = np.bincount(x) #count frequency of each element


#convert to dict
d = {}
ctr = 0 
while ctr < len(y):
    d[ctr] = y[ctr]
    ctr += 1
```

Comment: Ah, not looked at numpy.bincount() before. Thanks. Dictionary can be created quickly with: 
keys = numpy.flatnonzero(y)
values = y[keys]
d = dict(zip(keys, values))

Answer (score 0):

If you are allergic to Counter ([the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333560/298607) BTW), you can use setdefault:

```
d={}
for key in (e for sl in list_of_lists for e in sl): 
    d[key] = d.setdefault(key,0) + 1
```